# Can a density operator be written equivalently as $\rho=\sum_i p_i|\psi_i〉\!\langle\psi_i|$ and $\rho=\sum_i\lambda_i|\psi_i\rangle\!\langle\psi_i|$?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, density-matrix, nielsen-and-chuang, terminology-and-notation

My doubt arises from page *99, 101* of the book **[Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](http://mjg.global.s3.amazonaws.com/static/projects/refs/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information.pdf)** by *Michael A.Nielson and Issac L.Chung*.

Let {${p_{i}, | \psi_{i} \rangle }$} be an ensemble of pure states.

The density operator for this system can be defined by the equation:

$$\rho = \sum_{i} p_{i} |\psi_{i} \rangle \langle \psi_{i} |$$

On page 101, the author expressed the definition for a density operator like

$$\rho = \sum_{i} \lambda_{i} |\psi_{i} \rangle \langle \psi_{i} |$$

where $\lambda_{i}$ are the eigenvalues of the eigenstate $|\psi_{i} \rangle$.

The only relevant knowledge I do have on hand is the fact that the square of eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ yields the probability $p_{i} = |\lambda_{i}|^{2}$ that the measurement outcome of an eigenstate $|\psi_{i} \rangle$ is $\lambda_{i}$. Can someone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement $\rho=\sum_ip_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle \psi_i|$ is a very general way of writing down the density matrix. It must be noted that if you are simply presented with the matrix $\rho$, there are many different ensembles $\{p_i,|\psi_i\rangle\}$ that correspond to that matrix. Critically, $\rho$ is Hermitian, meaning that it has a spectral decomposition. This guarantees that one way of writing it (indeed, the one using the minimal number of terms) is in terms of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors $\{\lambda_i,|\phi_i\rangle\}$ (I've used $\phi$ here for the eigenvectors to distinguish from the general case of arbitrary vectors $\psi$).

Comment: Thank you.

How does the eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$ in 
$$\sum_{i} \lambda_{i} |\phi_{i} \rangle \langle \phi_{i} |$$

leads to the probability $p_{i}$ in definition of the density matrix $\rho$?

Comment: it is a probability: for a density matrix, the trace is 1, so the eigenvalues sum to 1 (like a probability) and each is bounded between 0 and 1.

Comment: I want to add one comment to this, which is that there are infinitely many ensembles which correspond to the same density matrix. The mapping of ensembles to density matrix is a surjective map.

Comment: @DaftWullie Understood. I wonder if my confusion stems from the use of notation here. The mod square of an eigenvalue yields a probability so, to be explicit, should $\lambda_{i}$ be $\lambda_{i}^{2}$ instead?

Comment: No. The mod-square of a probability amplitude yields a probability. Here, by virtue of being in a density matrix, you have already implicitly taken the mod-square, so it really is the $\lambda_i$ that are the probabilities.

Comment: @DaftWullie Thank you for getting this confusion out of the way.

Comment: @FDGod This really puts across what I understood after reading DaftWullie's contribution. Thank you for the confirmation.